# Magento 1.9.2.4 after checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9

When I order form my site, it does not show "Thank you for your order" page. Moreover order fails for no reason. Please help.

Comment: This is a place for you to get question answered. Please describe the exact thing you want answered.

Comment: After checkout, the cart page reflects saying you don't have anything in the cart.

Comment: Possibly the old 'form key' issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging in magento and check the log files for relevant errors. Also enable debug option in payment gateways and check their log files to see errors relating the payments.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.